# css selector for selector

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML Element:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-info">Feedback</div>
```

Class contains three elements:

- `btn` - style for default button
- `btn-xs` - changed size for button (not default one)
- `btn-info` - changed color for button (not default one)

This is 3th party library (bootstrap) that designs my button.

My question: Is it possible to make css selector where I summarize css selectors to one?

In my case it would look like:

```
<button type="button" class="feedback">Feedback</div>
```

And in my css:

```
.feedback {
  style: .btn; /* how to do that? */
  style: .btn-xs;
  style: .btn-info;
}
```

Comment: You might want to look into SASS or LESS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

CSS has no way to define a rule-set that imports rules from other rule-sets.

You can change your original rule-sets so they have a [group](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#grouping) of selectors:

```
.feedback, .btn { /* rules */ }
.feedback, .btn-xs { /* rules */ }
.feedback, .btn-info { /* rules */ }
```

Comment: What youre suggesting is right but he can't do that since he already said _This is 3th party library_

Comment: Exactly, I don't like to touch 3th party library

Comment: Anyway, is answers my question (it's not possible :()